# IOS authentication and Java application on JBoss

Tags: java, ios, rest, authentication

I have a Java application running on Jboss AS. I'm coding ios application and I need code for authentication in it.

Is it will be good possible way using REST service on Java app that will be check userName and hash of password.

Now I'm try this:
On Java I write REST method:

```
@GET

@Path("/checkAuth/{userName}/{passHash}")

@Produces("application/json")

public AuthResult checkAuth(@PathParam("userName") String userName, @PathParam("passHash")   String passwordHash) {

   // code for checking hash of Password with that in SQL base

}
```

On IOS app:

```
NSString *authRequest = [ NSString stringWithFormat: pathToRestWithParams, login, md5PassHash];

NSURL *restURL = [NSURL URLWithString:authRequest];
NSMutableURLRequest *restRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:restURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:180];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *restError = nil;
NSData *authResult = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:restRequest returningResponse:&response error:&restError];
```

**Is it secure?**

I want to add Java code that will be returned Session Key (Generated on Java app) for any user. This session key will be send with REST request for updating data from ios app.

Is it more secure?

Answer (score 0):

My Opinion is **NO**, because it is more vulnerable to man in middle attacks by stealing session id, Also MD5 is outdated now you can use **SHA-256 or 512** for hashing and salted password hashing will improve the security.
Refer [this **link** for more secure hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

For good security you need to apply **encryption like AES-256** to your payload , especially for authentication service and other sensitive data transmission.

Refer This link for more about  [java-iOS AES encryption-decryption](http://watchitlater.com/blog/2010/02/java-and-iphone-aes-interoperability/)